# Understand Assembly Code

Tags: assembly

```
   0x08048d02 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048d03 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048d05 <+3>: push   %esi
   0x08048d06 <+4>: push   %ebx
   0x08048d07 <+5>: sub    $0x30,%esp       //minus 48 to esp
   0x08048d0a <+8>: lea    -0x20(%ebp),%eax     //eax = first element in the array

   0x08048d0d <+11>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)       //
   0x08048d11 <+15>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax       //input?
   0x08048d14 <+18>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)      //esp = eax
   0x08048d17 <+21>:    call   0x804914a <read_six_numbers>

   0x08048d1c <+26>:    cmpl   $0x0,-0x20(%ebp)     // first int compare to 0

   0x08048d20 <+30>:    jns    0x8048d27 <phase_2+37>   //if not negative, jump

   0x08048d22 <+32>:    call   0x8049108 <explode_bomb> // < 0

   0x08048d27 <+37>:    mov    $0x1, %ebx       //set ebx = 1
   0x08048d2c <+42>:    lea    -0x20(%ebp),%esi     //set esi to the address of the first element of the array
   0x08048d2f <+45>:    mov    -0x4(%esi,%ebx,4),%eax   //eax = esi + ebx * 4 - 4
   0x08048d33 <+49>:    sub    %ebx,%eax        //ebx  = ebx - eax
   0x08048d35 <+51>:    cmp    %eax,(%esi,%ebx,4)   //eax = (esi + ebx * 4)

   0x08048d38 <+54>:    je     0x8048d3f <phase_2+61>

   0x08048d3a <+56>:    call   0x8049108 <explode_bomb>

   0x08048d3f <+61>:    add    $0x1,%ebx        //ebx = 2;
   0x08048d42 <+64>:    cmp    $0x6,%ebx        //if (ebx < 6)
   0x08048d45 <+67>:    jne    0x8048d2f <phase_2+45>   //do the loop again.

   0x08048d47 <+69>:    add    $0x30,%esp       //add 48 to esp.
   0x08048d4a <+72>:    pop    %ebx
   0x08048d4b <+73>:    pop    %esi
   0x08048d4c <+74>:    pop    %ebp
   0x08048d4d <+75>:    ret
```

I have the assembly code above, the goal for this is to not reach "explode_bomb".
I have commented my work and it seems that it will take 6 numbers and check them. I found that they have a for loop so the next number always equal to the former number * 4 - 4, so I tried things like 
x, 4x-4, 4(4x-4), etc.... where x > 0 but it doesn't work. Can someone point out what's the issue here? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, the bomb again. Haven't seen this phase yet ;)

You seem to be confused by `mov -0x4(%esi,%ebx,4),%eax` and `cmp %eax,(%esi,%ebx,4)`. The arithmetic there applies to the pointers, not the values. Basically, the first is `array[i-1]` and the second is `array[i]`, with `ebx` being `i` (the array index) and `esi` is the base address. The multiplication by `4` is because each element is `4` bytes long.

As such, the loop goes something like this:

```
for(i = 1; i != 6; i++)
{
    if (array[i - 1] - i != array[i]) explode_bomb();
}
```

The first element can be any number greater than or equal to zero, as such a possible solution is `0`, `-1`, `-3`, `-6`, `-10`, `-15`.

Comment: thanks so much for the help. Now I understand a bit better. When you say the first is "array[i-1]" and the second is "array[i]". Which one is the "first"?

Comment: `-0x4(%esi,%ebx,4)` is the first expression, that's `array[i - 1]`.

Comment: thanks so much. Now it makes sense. So %eax stands for array[i] ?